# Can I add all products from all product pages to a single array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

The Shopify REST API uses pagination to display products. The default number of products per page is 50, but the limit can be set to 250. One must make multiple calls to the API using the link to the next page provided in the previous response.

**My problem** is that I cannot get my code to the point of paginating through ~1,300 products and concatenating them to a single array `allProducts`. As seen under `response.json` below, the first page of products appears correctly, but never any subsequent pages. I have attempted to define the link:

```
const headerLink = products.headers.Link[0]
```

`response.json` has the following schema, hence `headerLink`:

```
[
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 81226235887,
        "title": "title",
        .....
    ],
    "headers": {
      ...
      "Link": [
        "<https://{EXAMPLE}.com/admin/api/2023-04/products.json?limit=50&page_info=yJsYXN0X2lkIjo4MTIyNDIxNzcyNTkxLCJsYXN0X3ZhbHsafwegVlIjoiMTRLIFJvc2UgNSBtbSBDdXNoaW9JKDAuIEZvmluZyIsImRpcmVsdawejdGlvbiI6Im5leHQifQ>; rel=\"next\""
      ],
      ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

`rel=\"next\""` in my code below indicates that there's another page available. If we had reached the last page already, this line would be missing in the response. My code references it in

```
const match = headerLink.match(/<[^;]+\/(\w+\.json[^;]+)>;\srel="next"/);
```

My code seems to spit out the same link repeatedly:

```
The next link:  https://example.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-04/products.json?limit=50&page_info=yJsYXN0X2lkIjo4MTIyNDIxNzcyNTkxLCJsYXN0X3ZhbHsafwegVlIjoiMTRLIFJvc2UgNSBtbSBDdXNoaW9JKDAuIEZvmluZyIsImRpcmVsdawejdGlvbiI6Im5leHQifQ
```

My code:

```
/**
 * FILEPATH: /Users/christopherkonicki/Documents/GitHub/Import_Stuller_Nivoda/deleteMe.js
 * 
 * This script imports all products from a Shopify store using the Shopify REST API.
 * It uses the 'shopify' and 'session' objects from the 'testingShopifyApp.js' file.
 * 
 * The 'makeRequest' function makes a request to the Shopify API to get all products.
 * It uses pagination to get all products, since the API returns a maximum of 250 products per request.
 * 
 * The 'allProducts' array stores all products retrieved from the API.
 * The 'since_id' variable is used to keep track of the last product ID retrieved from the API.
 * 
 * The function returns a Promise that resolves with the 'allProducts' array when all products have been retrieved.
 */
// In another .js file in the same directory
import { shopify } from './testingShopifyApp.js';
import { session } from './testingShopifyApp.js';
import "@shopify/shopify-api/adapters/node";

const client = new shopify.clients.Rest({session});

let allProducts = [];
let since_id = 0;

/**
 * This function makes a request to the Shopify API to get all products.
 * It uses pagination to get all products, since the API returns a maximum of 250 products per request.
 * 
 * The 'nextLink' parameter is used to specify the URL of the next page of products to retrieve.
 * If no 'nextLink' is provided, the function starts by retrieving the first page of products.
 * 
 * The function returns a Promise that resolves with an array of all products retrieved from the API.
 */
function makeRequest(nextLink = 'https://{EXAMPLE}.com/admin/api/2023-04/products.json') {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let products = [];
        // Make a request to the Shopify API to get the next page of products
        fetch(nextLink).then(async r => {
            // If this is the first page of products, use the Shopify REST API to get all products
            if (since_id === 0) {
                products = await shopify.rest.Product.all({
                    session,
                    query: {
                        since_id: 0,
                        fields: 'id,title,images',
                    },
                });
                allProducts = allProducts.concat(products);
                console.log('All products so far: ', allProducts[0]);
            };
            // If this is not the first page of products, use the 'since_id' parameter to get all products since the last product retrieved
            if (since_id !== 0) {
                let headerLink = products.headers.Link[0];
                while (headerLink) {
                    products = await shopify.rest.Product.all({
                        session,
                        query: {
                            since_id: since_id,
                            fields: 'id,title,images',
                        },
                    });
                    allProducts = allProducts.concat(products);
                    console.log('All products so far: ', allProducts[0]);
                    headerLink = products.headers.Link[0];
                }
            }
            // Get the URL of the next page of products from the 'Link' header of the API response
            const headerLink = products.headers.Link[0];
            const match = headerLink.match(/<[^;]+\/(\w+\.json[^;]+)>;\srel="next"/);
            const nextLink = match ? `https://{EXAMPLE}.com/admin/api/2023-04/${match[1]}` : false;
            console.log('The next link: ', nextLink);
            // If there is a next page of products, recursively call this function with the URL of the next page
            if (nextLink) {
                makeRequest(nextLink);
            } else {
                // If there are no more pages of products, resolve the Promise with the array of all products retrieved
                resolve(allProducts[0]);
            }
        }).catch(reject);
    });
}

// Call the 'makeRequest' function to start retrieving all products from the Shopify API
makeRequest();
```

Comment: Out of interest why would you need to do this? The API retrieving only a subset of records is a far better UX.

Comment: @Andy - I have connections with suppliers. I figured if everything was in a single array, I could just run it once daily and then run the backend script to see if there were any product changes from the suppliers. For instance, if an item were sold out at the supplier, I would need to update that item in my store.

Answer (score 0):

For this specific purpose shopify has an inbuilt graphql solution **Bulk Query**

[Bulk Query Shopify](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/usage/bulk-operations/queries)